# Do you know of any fonts where letters that are normally below baseline (g, y, p, q) are written completely above the baseline in lowercase?

Tags: fonts, text, interface-design, button

I'm looking for a font in which letters which are normally lower than the baseline (g, y, p, q) are written completely above the baseline when in lowercase.  I'm looking for such a font for the game I'm designing.  I've done some surfing around the internet but cannot find a font like this. I don't want a font which resorts to uppercase for these letters. Could you direct me to such a font?

Comment: Any font that duplicates the appearance of a HD44780 text LCD display will have the desired feature - but 5x7 blocky text might not be the look you're going for.

Comment: Could you explain why you want such a font? What makes it desirable for your use case?

Comment: @JackAidley I’m looking for such a font for certain menu buttons in a game I’m designing

Comment: @jasonharper You’re right, I’m not looking for a blocky font

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a **Unicase** font. There are several.

Try here: https://www.myfonts.com/search?query=unicase

Comment: I chose this as the answer because it gives me the most choices for the font I’m looking for, some of which are significantly cheaper than in other answers.  Ideally I was actually hoping for a free font

Comment: There *may* be free unicase fonts out in the wild. You'd have to search for those at free font sites. For the most part, I don't use free fonts. They inevitably prove to be problematic in many instance.

Answer (score 4):

Try Spartan Classified (a.k.a. [Geometric 212](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/geometric-212-font-bitstream)) for small sizes or [Media Sans by Production Type](https://www.productiontype.com/family/media_sans) for headline sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Searching by "large x-height font", I found next one: https://www.1001fonts.com/ticketing-font.html

Comment: A font with a large x-height can still have descenders.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure, and mostly they have :) This was just alternate search term.

Comment: That was my complaint, you're using a term that is completely irrelevant to the question, thus unhelpful.  Congratulations if that search term helped you find a suitable font, but how many unsuitable ones did you have to dig through before you found it?  You would have had just as much luck going through every possible font.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this font's that i personally found good and very eye catchy

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cormorant+Unicase
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Delius+Unicase
https://fontstruct.com/gallery/set/95/unicase
https://www.fontsc.com/font/tag/unicase